# Cannot read from asset file: /home/dev.assets.yaml when trying to use sep-24 and sep-38

Tags: assets, anchor

I'm trying to run sep-24 and sep-38 on my dev.assest.yaml file but I keep having this error:

```
Reason: Cannot read from asset file: /home/dev.assets.yaml
platform-server_1   | 
platform-server_1   | 
platform-server_1   | Action:
platform-server_1   | 
platform-server_1   | Update your application's configuration
below is my asset file
```

```
# dev.assets.yaml
assets:
  - schema: stellar
    code: USDC
    issuer: GBBD47IF6LWK7P7MDEVSCWR7DPUWV3NY3DTQEVFL4NAT4AQH3ZLLFLA5
    distribution_account: GBLSAHONJRODSFTLOV225NZR4LHICH63RIFQTQN37L5CRTR2IMQ5UEK7
    significant_decimals: 2
    sep24_enabled: true
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
  - schema: iso4217
    code: USD
    significant_decimals: 2
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
  - schema: stellar
    code: native
    distribution_account: GBLSAHONJRODSFTLOV225NZR4LHICH63RIFQTQN37L5CRTR2IMQ5UEK7
    significant_decimals: 7
    sep24_enabled: true
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
    sep31_enabled: true
    sep38_enabled: true
    send:
      min_amount: 0
      max_amount: 10000
    sep31:
      quotes_supported: true
      quotes_required: true
      fields:
        transaction: {}
      sep12:
        sender:
          types:
            sep31-sender:
              description: customers sending to recipients
        receiver:
          types:
            sep31-receiver:
              description: customers receiving from senders
    sep38:
      exchangeable_assets:
        - iso4217:NGN
      country_codes:
        - NG
  - schema: iso4217
    code: NGN
    sep38_enabled: true
    sep38:
      exchangeable_assets:
        - stellar:USDC:GBBD47IF6LWK7P7MDEVSCWR7DPUWV3NY3DTQEVFL4NAT4AQH3ZLLFLA5
      country_codes:
        - NG
      significant_decimals: 2
      buy_delivery_methods:
        - name: PIX
          description: Have NGN sent directly to your bank account.
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the sep31 and sep38 out of the stellar:native scheme puts your anchor up and running.

Native asset does not support SEP-31 or SEP-38

This should work:

```
# dev.assets.yaml
assets:
  - schema: stellar
    code: USDC
    issuer: GBBD47IF6LWK7P7MDEVSCWR7DPUWV3NY3DTQEVFL4NAT4AQH3ZLLFLA5
    distribution_account: GBLSAHONJRODSFTLOV225NZR4LHICH63RIFQTQN37L5CRTR2IMQ5UEK7
    significant_decimals: 2
    sep24_enabled: true
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
  - schema: iso4217
    code: USD
    significant_decimals: 2
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
  - schema: stellar
    code: native
    distribution_account: GBLSAHONJRODSFTLOV225NZR4LHICH63RIFQTQN37L5CRTR2IMQ5UEK7
    significant_decimals: 7
    sep24_enabled: true
    deposit:
      enabled: true
    withdraw:
      enabled: true
    send:
      min_amount: 0
      max_amount: 10000
  - schema: iso4217
    code: NGN
    sep38_enabled: true
    sep38:
      exchangeable_assets:
        - stellar:USDC:GBBD47IF6LWK7P7MDEVSCWR7DPUWV3NY3DTQEVFL4NAT4AQH3ZLLFLA5
      country_codes:
        - NG
      significant_decimals: 2
      buy_delivery_methods:
        - name: PIX
          description: Have NGN sent directly to your bank account.
```